# Difference between single-pointer and double-pointer arrays

Tags: c++, pointers

Code below prints addresses of dynamically allocated array. Printed addresses become slightly different, when new line starts. If I use static array, addresses are exactly the same, and array elements are going one after another. What's the reason?

```
void func(int* a, int** b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << &a[i * n + j]<< " " << &b[i][j]<< endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int** a;
    a = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = new int[n];
    }
    func(a[0], a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Difference between single-pointer and double-pointer arrays

You can see the difference in the code:

```
int** a;         // a is a pointer of type int**
a = new int*[n]; // a points to an array of pointers of type int*
```

And:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i] = new int[n]; // a[i] points to an array of ints
```

There you have it.

> Printed addresses become slightly different, when new line starts. If I use static array, addresses are exactly the same, and array elements are going one after another.

Presumably, you're talking about a static array of arrays and compare it to the array of pointers that you have.

Elements of an array are allocated continuously in memory. In the case of array of static arrays, the elements of the outer array are static arrays and they are stored continuously in memory. In the case of array of pointers, the elements of the outer array are the pointers and they are also stored continuously in memory. The arrays of `int` that you allocate dynamically on the other hand are not stored in the outer array. Where they're stored  is implementation defined and typically not related to the location of the array which holds the pointers.

Also:

```
cout << &a[i * n + j]<< " " << &b[i][j]<< endl;
```

Here you're accessing beyond the borders of the array pointed by the argument `a` which is pointed by `a[0]` in `main` and has a length of `n` which is less than `i * n + j` when `i` is non-zero. The result is technically undefined behaviour and the printed addresses are most definitely not of the elements of arrays that you've allocated.

Comment: Thank you for reply!

Yes, but are the bytes after each line allocated randomly? If I change array type, then I could see, that their number is fixed to 8+sizeof(type). And I have 64 bit system, so could it be something like sizeof(pointer)+sizeof(type)?

Comment: @Vasily If I understand you correctly, you're asking about the relative location of each dynamically allocated array in memory. Such details are not specified by the standard and are up to the compiler implementation to decide.

Answer (score 0):

It's how you created your matrix. There is no reason to assume that `a[0] + 1 * n + j` equals `a[1] + j`. `a[0]` and `a[1]` were independently allocated.

Here is a way to get the entire matrix at once.

```
int** a = new int*[n]; // allocate the row indexes
a[0] = new int[n * n]; // allocate the entire matrix
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    a[i] = a[0] + i * n; // assign the row indexes. NOTE: a[0] is already assigned.
}
```

Using this allocation, `a[0] + 1 * n + j` equals `a[1] + j`.

---

Static arrays allocate the entire matrix allocation implicitly, which is why your code works for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Code below prints addresses of dynamically allocated array. 
Printed addresses become slightly different, when new line starts. If
I use static array, addresses are exactly the same, and array elements
are going one after another. What's the reason?
```

The reason being that The following call will generate a new address every-time it is called and there is no guarantee of that address being contiguous.
    a[i] = new int[n];

While,

> int a[10][20]

which is a static array  will have contiguous memory allocation.

Comment: `int a[10\[20];` is not necessarily static.  If it's a local variable, it's automatic, not static.

Comment: @JamesKanze isn't *static* in *static array* in this context used to refer to the *length* being static (compiletime) rather than dynamic (runtime)? In the same sense as `statc_assert` is a compiletime `assert`? Rather than referring to the type of allocation. I was under such impression.

Comment: @user2079303 If so, it's a confusing use, since in C++, static has a definite meaning when applied to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're using two conflicting implementations in your modeling of
a matrix: in `main`, you use arrays of arrays, with each row in
separate memory; and in `func`, you assume a single flat array
of `rows * columns` elements, mapping the two indices to one.
You have to choose one or the other.

In C++, of course, you'd write a `Matrix` class, to encapsulate
this choice.  For example, if you wanted the single flat array
(usually preferable), you'd write something like:

```
class Matrix
{
    int myRowCount;
    int myColumnCount;
    std::vector<int> myData;
public:
    Matrix( int rows, int columns )
        : myRowCount( rows )
        , myColumnCount( columns )
        , myData( rows * columns )
    {
    }

    int& operator()( int row, int column )
    {
        assert( row >= 0 && row < myRowCount
                && column >= 0 && column < myColumnCount );
        return myData[row * myColumnCount + column];
    }

    int const& operator()( int row, int column ) const
    {
        assert( row >= 0 && row < myRowCount
                && column >= 0 && column < myColumnCount );
        return myData[row * myColumnCount + column];
    }
};
```

You'll note that I used `std::vector` rather than doing any
dynamic allocation myself.  In this case, the difference isn't
enormous, but in practice, no experienced C++ programmer would
use an array new except in very exceptional cases; one
sometimes wonders why it is even in the language.

You'll also note that I have overloaded the `()` operator for
indexing.  You cannot provide two indices for `[]`, and this is
one of the solutions to that problem.  Alternatively,
`operator[]` would take a single index, and return a proxy
object which would also take a single index.  While this is the
solution I prefer, it is more complicated.